# Sonatype Nexus 3 - get latest snapshot

Tags: java, maven, nexus, nexus3

We've just upgraded out nexus installation to the latest release (3.x). Is there any way to get the latest version of a given snapshot artifact? Nexus 2 had a nice API which is not supported anymore.

Same question (but for the old version) has been answered here:
[Sonatype Nexus REST Api fetch latest build version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783859/sonatype-nexus-rest-api-fetch-latest-build-version)

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Best,
Daniel

Comment: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html#_writing_scripts ?

Comment: looks it's about nexus plugins, not for getting data via REST API

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Asof April 2019 there IS a REST API in Sonatype Nexus 3 for accessing the latest artefact

Documentation is here

http://community.sonatype.com/t/nxrm-3-16-rest-search-and-filtering-enhancements/1586

Use this endpoint `/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download` with `repository`, `group` and `name` arguments. Sorting by `version` will get you the latest timestamped snapshot.

https://nexus.blahblah.com/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?repository=maven-snapshots&group=com.my.company&name=myArtefact&sort=version&direction=desc

Comment: 2 shots of whiskey to this gentleman! This solved exactly my use case: having a link that automatically retrieves the most recent snapshot/release.

Comment: You can also narrow the search using wildcards, for example: &version=2.1*
(tested on OSS 3.21.2)

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer and example link!

Comment: There are a few more useful parameters, e.g. `&maven.baseVersion=master-SNAPSHOT&maven.classifier=sql&maven.extension=zip`

Comment: Also note that if using curl, you will need the `-L` option to actually download the found artifact, as well as the `-o` option to specify the output file name.

Answer (score 6):

> Nexus 2 had a nice API which is not supported anymore.

It sounds like you are referring to these:

```
/service/local/artifact/maven/content
/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect
```

> If you're asking to find the latest x.y.z-SNAPSHOT version where the x, y, z are guessed - Nexus never had this functionality (it worked only for plugins).

This is simply untrue - see the following article which shows clearly you can specify LATEST, RELEASE or SNAPSHOT base versions.

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465488-How-can-I-retrieve-a-snapshot-if-I-don-t-know-the-exact-filename-

> It's possible but not in a 1-liner.

Yes - unless you have a tool handy such as [artifact-resolver](https://github.com/sonatype/artifact-resolver) which does uses a one line command to fetch an artifact.

Answer (score 4):

What a joke re: Nexus 3 having no REST API.

I found a hack that alleviates my problem.  Turns out that ansible has a nice [maven_artifact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/maven_artifact_module.html) module that is somehow able to figure out the latest snapshot.  And you can run ansible locally.  So it ends up looking like this:

```
ansible all -i localhost, -c local -m maven_artifact -a "repository_url=https://my-nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/ group_id=com.whatever artifact_id=my-artifact version=2.0-SNAPSHOT dest=./my-artifact.jar"
```

Comment: That doesn't explain how to download the latest snapshot if it isn't 2.0-SNAPSHOT by accident.

Answer (score 4):

Bash one-liner using `curl`, `jq`, `sort` and `tail` :

```
NEXUS_URL=https://your-nexus.com
MAVEN_REPO=maven-snapshots
GROUP_ID=...
ARTIFACT_ID=...
VERSION=2.0.1-SNAPSHOT
FILE_EXTENSION=jar

download_url=$(curl -X GET "${NEXUS_URL}/service/rest/v1/search/assets?repository=${MAVEN_REPO}&maven.groupId=${GROUP_ID}&maven.artifactId=${ARTIFACT_ID}&maven.baseVersion=${VERSION}&maven.extension=${FILE_EXTENSION}" -H  "accept: application/json"  | jq -rc '.items | .[].downloadUrl' | sort | tail -n 1)

wget $download_url
```

Comment: you are great! :)

Comment: Like to echo that first comment, you are the greatest! This saved me while trying to building a docker image for deploying snapshots into our cluster. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you ask for `x.y.z-SNAPSHOT` then by default the latest `x.y.z-timestamp` snapshot version will be downloaded. No need to do anything additional

If you're asking to find the latest `x.y.z-SNAPSHOT` version where the `x`, `y`, `z` are guessed - [Nexus never had this functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911620/using-the-nexus-rest-api-to-get-latest-artifact-version-for-given-groupid-artifa/25951599#25951599) (it worked only for plugins). And I don't think there is any good use case for this. If this is needed, you're probably doing something wrong. You always should work with a specific version. Actually even for the 1st functionality I can't think of good use cases.

Answer (score 1):

recently we faced the same problem with nexus version 3.12.1-01, so there is definitely not rest api to get latest snapshot directly

we were able to solve the problem using python one liner

```
JSON_RESPONSE=$(curl -u un:pw -X GET "http://nexus-host/nexus/service/rest/beta/search/assets?maven.groupId=sample.group.id&maven.artifactId=sample&maven.extension=jar" -H  "accept: application/json")

echo $JSON_RESPONSE | python -c 'import sys, json; lines = json.load(sys.stdin)["items"]; sortedlines = sorted(lines, key=lambda k: k["downloadUrl"], reverse=True); print(sortedlines[0]["downloadUrl"])'
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can download with curl

```
curl -L --header 'Accept: application/json' "https://${NEXUS_URL}/service/rest/beta/search/assets/download?repository=${NEXUS_REPO_NAME}&maven.groupId=${MVN_GROUP_ID}&maven.artifactId=${MVN_ARTIFACT_ID}&maven.baseVersion=${APP_VERSION}&maven.extension=${MVN_EXTENSION}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using OSS 3.21.2-03 I have retrieved latest snapshot with following url on a zip extension file :

```
{nexus_host}/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&repository={repository_name}&group={group_id}&name={artifact-id}&maven.extension=zip
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but not in a 1-liner.  You need to fetch the maven-metadata.xml for each snapshot artifact you're after (note that multi-module projects have different timestamps for each module including the parent).

We use [xlstproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) to extract the relevant variables so we are still able to run from the command line without heavyweight tools like maven or ivy to do the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a groovy script that can be uploaded to Nexus which solves this particular issue with a POST request.

You can find the script and some usage instructions here: https://github.com/rbjorklin/resolve-latest-nexus-artifact

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wasn't getting anything back because I was missing the credentials require for my Nexus Server. Once I added them to both the CURL and WGET command, it worked for me.

```
NEXUS_URL=https://your-nexus.com
MAVEN_REPO=maven-snapshots
GROUP_ID=...
ARTIFACT_ID=...
VERSION=2.0.1-SNAPSHOT
FILE_EXTENSION=jar

download_url=$(curl --user admin:yourpassword -X GET "${NEXUS_URL}/service/rest/v1/search/assets?repository=${MAVEN_REPO}&maven.groupId=${GROUP_ID}&maven.artifactId=${ARTIFACT_ID}&maven.baseVersion=${VERSION}&maven.extension=${FILE_EXTENSION}" -H  "accept: application/json"  | jq -rc '.items | .[].downloadUrl' | sort | tail -n 1)

wget --user=admin --password=mypassword $download_url
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum up on top of [user1717259](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1717259/user1717259)'s answer (using **Nexus 3.37.3-02**).

Bash one-liner using `curl` and `sed`:

```sh
BASE_URL="https://your-nexus-server.com"

# All of the following query parameters are optional, and 
# defaults to <empty> if not specified otherwise, and
# wildcards can be used as well.

params="repository=<the-repository-id>"

params+="&maven.groupId=<the-group-id>"
params+="&maven.artifactId=<the-atifact-id>"
params+="&maven.baseVersion=<the-version>"   # can be <empty>, `1.2.3`, `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`, or `1.2.*`, etc.
params+="&maven.extendsion=<the-extension>"
params+="&maven.classifier=<the-classifier>"

params+="&sort=<the-sort-field>"             # can be <empty>, `group`, `name`, `version`, 'repository'
params+="&direction=<the-sort-direction>"    # can be `asc`, and `desc` (the default)
params+="&prerelease=<empty, true, or false>" # default (<empty>) to search releases and prereleases

DOWNLOAD_URL=$(curl -s -k -i "$BASE_URL/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?$params" | sed -n -E 's/^Location: ([^\r\n]+).*$/\1/p')
```

Version comparison examples:

`1.2.3` < `1.3.0-SNAPSHOT` < `1.3.0-CD2-SNAPSHOT` < `1.3.0-CD12-SNAPSHOT` < `1.3.0-RC1` < `1.3.0` < `1.4.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Nexus 3.37 has a but about this right ? Is this a workaround ?

Comment: issue : https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-30694