# Download artifact from Nexus OSS 3.0.0-03 using browser/wget

Tags: maven, repository, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I have a local installation of Nexus OSS 3.0.0-03.

I am able to upload snapshot and release jars.

Now I want to download those jars via the browser or wget, but I can't seem to find the REST API call to do it (for example in a shell script executed by Jenkins).

Prior to version 3 it seems one could use something like:
http://MY_REPOSITORY/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?r=repoId&g=groupName&a=art&v=LATEST

Any ideas on how to do this with version 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonatype Nexus 3 - get latest snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280818/sonatype-nexus-3-get-latest-snapshot)

Answer (score 0):

If it's latest you are looking for, you can see the answer here: [Sonatype Nexus 3 - get latest snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280818/sonatype-nexus-3-get-latest-snapshot/41556540#41556540)

This as of yet does not exist in Nexus Repository 3 but is coming in the nearish future as we revamp the REST API.

However, if you want to download an artifact and know it's coordinates, you can do that via constructing a URL using the patterns here as a helpful tool: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Remote+repository+layout#Remoterepositorylayout-Repositoryartifactlayout