# Nexus 3 : how to get latest snapshot?

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

As we all know Nexus 3 does not have REST API yet, which is very weird for me. I can only download artifacts manually using wget or curl. But as I'm using Maven 3, all the snapshots artifacts are named using timestamps like this :

```
myartifact-1.0-20161215.141522-4.tar.gz
```

So I want to know how I can get latest snapshots from a repo? I want to automate the download process of artifacts but as names change I didn't find any way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: Why do you use Nexus 3 together with Maven?

Comment: Because our project is based on maven(Java), what would you do?

Comment: We use Nexus 2.x until Nexus 3 fully satisfies our needs.

Comment: Just to mention: I'm not sure about Nexus, but it's possible with Artifactory. E.g. I created a tiny script which downloads artifacts for me at work and uses REST API. You can see it here: https://github.com/pwittchen/ydownloader. If you're able to update your infrastructure, you may consider such option.

Comment: Sadly we have used Nexus 3 for several months, and cannot go back to Nexus 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonatype Nexus 3 - get latest snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280818/sonatype-nexus-3-get-latest-snapshot)

Comment: Nexus 3 now has the REST API you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280818/sonatype-nexus-3-get-latest-snapshot/57512496#57512496

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If keeping only one SNAPSHOT in the repository is a valid option

This API call will work: `${nexusUrl}/service/rest/beta/search/assets/download?maven.groupId=${groupId}&maven.artifactId=${artifactId}&maven.baseVersion=${version}`

Though there is finally a [Nexus3 API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api) (see more on this [in Sonatype's blog](https://blog.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-new-beta-rest-api-for-content)), the API does not yet provide the means to get the last SNAPSHOT version. This situation will hopefully be improved in the future: [NEXUS-14407](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14407) is tracking this feature request.

But until then I'm workarounding the problem by defining a `Maven - Delete SNAPSHOT` Task:

[image: Maven - Delete SNAPSHOT]

and configuring it to run every minute deleting all but 1 snapshot versions older than 0 days:

[image]

Comment: This is a very useful answer. Asof April 2019 the feature has been added. The documentation is here http://community.sonatype.com/t/nxrm-3-16-rest-search-and-filtering-enhancements/1586.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a script in Groovy and upload it to Nexus to do what you want.

Here's an example of a script I used to write to return all versions for a given group and repository.

Content of `version.json` :

```
{
  "name": "version",
  "type": "groovy",
  "content": "import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query;
    import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet;
    import groovy.json.JsonOutput;

    def groupId = args.split(',')[0];
    def repositoryId = args.split(',')[1];

    def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(repositoryId);
    StorageFacet storageFacet = repo.facet(StorageFacet);
    def tx = storageFacet.txSupplier().get();

   tx.begin();
   def components = tx.findComponents(Query.builder().where('group = ').param(groupId).build(), [repo]);
   def found = components.collect {
   def baseVersion = it.attributes().child('maven2').get('baseVersion');
   \"${baseVersion}\"
   };
   found = found.unique();
   tx.commit();
   def result = JsonOutput.toJson(found);

   return result;"
}
```

The interesting part here is the `tx.findComponents()` that returns generic `Component` class. This class provides extra information about its *container* with the function `attributes()`.
You can then use it to get the `baseVersion` i.e. the version Maven used to use (with the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix).

To install this script, just run the following :

```
curl -v -X POST -u <NEXUS_ADMIN>:<NEXUS_PWD> --header "Content-Type:application/json" http://<SERVER_NEXUS>/nexus/service/siesta/rest/v1/script -d @version.json
```

You can then test it easily with :

```
curl -v -X POST -u <NEXUS_ADMIN>:<NEXUS_PWD> --header "Content-Type: text/plain" "http://<SERVER_NEXUS>/nexus/service/siesta/rest/v1/script/version/run" -d "com.my.groupid,snapshots"
```

This will return all versions you want as you wanted :

```
{
  "name" : "version",
  "result" : "[\"1.5.2-SNAPSHOT\",\"1.5.3-SNAPSHOT\",\"1.6.1-SNAPSHOT\",\"1.5.0-SNAPSHOT\"]"
}
```

Hope this'll help !

Comment: I would highly recommend running this inside a try/finally block and closing the transaction (via `tx.close()`) inside the finally portion. I used this as the starting point for a script and after 12-48 hours of running my Nexus installation would hang and no longer respond to artifact requests. This script is even included in a [ticket](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14612) that describes my exact situation.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible. We are looking at use cases like this one specifically as we build the REST API and you should expect this functionality in the nearish future.

As alluded to in the comments, you might have a use case where it would be best to still use Nexus Repository Manager 2, for the time being. If you are handy with Groovy and scripting, you might also extend Nexus Repository Manager 3 via the Integration API to do what you describe (and I for one would love to see that). More info on using that is here: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/scripting.html

Comment: Hi are you Nexus developer? Yes I'm currently looking at the Groovy REST API, I made a Maven project and I would like to know do I suppose to upload the script to my Nexus repo and run the script by curl?

Comment: I am SORT OF a developer, meaning I write bad code from time to time. There are a plethora of scripts here (including shell scripts for upload, etc...) that you can lean on to do what you want to do: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/nexus-3.x/scripting/simple-shell-example

Comment: haha thank you, I already did a git clone but there's almost nothing in the example, only a javadoc which is not so useful.

Comment: You will want to use this script to upload a file (changing the username/password if necessary) https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/blob/nexus-3.x/scripting/simple-shell-example/create.sh and an example json file that you could modify with your script would be something akin to this: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/blob/nexus-3.x/scripting/simple-shell-example/maven.json

Answer (score 2):

Using the new REST API on Nexus v3 (exact version 3.17.0) the following request to retrieve the latest snapshot worked for me:

```
/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&maven.artifactId=artifactId&maven.baseVersion=x.y.z-SNAPSHOT&maven.extension=jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another post here: [Nexus 3 Rest api to check if component exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873731/nexus-3-rest-api-to-check-if-component-exist)

I commented in the

```
found = found.unique().sort();
```

line and called it with the following parameters:

```
-d'<reponame>,<groupid>,<artifactid>,<version>-SNAPSHOT,latest'
```

YMMV but this did it for me. I was then able to construct a wget with the result of this query.