# how do I tell maven 3.6.3 to get latest version of artifact from custom repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I need to download the latest version of artifact from custom repository rather than maven repository.(Download a latest single artifact from the custom repository)

I followed the [how do i tell maven to get latest version of artifact from custom nexus repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514208/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-get-latest-version-of-artifact-from-custom-nexus-reposito).

[How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency?rq=1)

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-latest-version

```
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.LDBS</groupId>
            <artifactId>LDBS</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>                 
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
   <repository>
       <id>org.demo.repo</id>
       <url>http://demoRepo/dependencies</url>
    </repository>
```

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

After including the version plugin (mvn versions:display-dependency-updates) I am able to see the latest new version
[image]

But I can't download that version to my local repo using following commands

- mvn versions:use-releases
- mvn versions:use-next-releases

  Still I am only getting the old snapshot version not the latest version jars from my custom repo. Eclipse mavendependencies too referring the old snapshots because latest version are not downloaded in local repo
  Any one please advise

Comment: This is not clear to me. Do you want to use the latest version in your build, or do you just want to download a single artifact from the repository?

Comment: @JFMeier Need to download a latest single artifact from the custom repository

Comment: Please add the current maven configuration for the dependency in question.

Comment: @Boris - Updated the question, pls check

Comment: See this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-latest-version).

Comment: @Boris Thanks,I tried including the version plugin too, Still latest version are not downloading from my custom

Comment: Please update the question with your attempt. And add the output of `$ mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207801/discussion-between-debugger-and-boris).