# bash script require which download latest version of the **war** (either snapshot or release ) file nexus repository in tomcat

Tags: bash, shell, continuous-integration, nexus, continuous-deployment

I need a bash script which download latest version of the **war** (either snapshot or release ) file nexus repository in tomcat

Please find me script. Need experts help

```
server="http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories"
repo="snapshots"
name="org/continuous/Integration"
artifact="Continuous-Integration"
path=$server/$repo/$name/$artifact
mvnMetadata=$(curl -s "$path/maven-metadata.xml")
```

Please find the nexus repository Image:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need a script which download the war file from nexus repository in to the tomcat webapps folder. I will use this script with Scalr (CAMP) which execute this script into new cloud instance and code will be deploy

Comment: I'm very new to the scripting...writing scripting first time

Answer (score 1):

last snapshot was downloaded with the help of Nexus rest API

wget --content-disposition "http://localhost:8080/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=snapshots&g=org.continuous.Integration&a=Continuous-Integration&v=LATEST&e=war"

Thanks DarthHater.It was working with rest API

Answer (score 0):

You can use the information available here [Using the Nexus rest API to get latest artifact version for given groupid/artifactId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911620/using-the-nexus-rest-api-to-get-latest-artifact-version-for-given-groupid-artifa) to construct the API call to do this. Shouldn't be very hard to piece the rest of the commands together from here (using curl or wget to do the download, for example).