# Download single/latest asset(JAR) from Nexus3

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, nexus, sonatype

I am trying to download the latest/newest asset(JAR) from my local Nexus repo. I am using Nexus Swagger UI. It has a GET method to download,

```
GET /beta/search/assets/download
```

The issue is..I have many assets in the repo, and it gives an error,

```
Search returned multiple assets, please refine search criteria to find a single asset
```

How do I refine my search & get the latest/newest JAR?

[image]

FYI.. currently, I have 20+ assets in the repo, below I am showing two of them..

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "downloadUrl": "http://localhost:8081/repository/snapshot/com/openshift/test/openshift-jenkins/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/openshift-jenkins-0.0.1-20180214.211251-17.jar",
      "path": "com/openshift/test/openshift-jenkins/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/openshift-jenkins-0.0.1-20180214.211251-17.jar",
      "id": "c25hcHNob3Q6ZTAxODhlZDA3MjhmYTY4ZmIwOGZkYzAyYTliZTQ4Zjg",
      "repository": "snapshot",
      "format": "maven2",
      "checksum": {
        "sha1": "53cdfcf964d0edd5fc6fdefa457e700eff47a1ca",
        "md5": "d0c82971b82957728d0b4c858150d56c"
      }
    },
    {
      "downloadUrl": "http://localhost:8081/repository/snapshot/com/openshift/test/openshift-jenkins/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/openshift-jenkins-0.0.1-20180214.210246-15.jar",
      "path": "com/openshift/test/openshift-jenkins/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/openshift-jenkins-0.0.1-20180214.210246-15.jar",
      "id": "c25hcHNob3Q6MjEwMzFkZmFmNDVlNWI1ODgwZTUwYjE5M2Y5NGVkNjk",
      "repository": "snapshot",
      "format": "maven2",
      "checksum": {
        "sha1": "b041f4b1e6bcb81366a72635f6c576ae46a83ec8",
        "md5": "af970e3e66c9cd20ff66f1074da04c21"
      }
    }
  ],
  "continuationToken": null
}
```

Comment: This is implemented with Nexus API 3.16. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48860228/6309).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a search, you might using an artifact redirtect (with curl -L being able to follow the redirection): [`/artifact/maven/redirect`](https://oss.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/path__artifact_maven_redirect.html)

```
curl -L "http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=log4j&a=log4j&v=LATEST" -o log4j.jar
```

However, it [might not be available for Nexus 3 yet](https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/#!topic/nexus-users/rNDLQiVBrlc).

In that case, you need to [download and parse first the `maven-metadata.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485418/6309).
You can extract from there the latest tag.

---

Sice Feb. 2018, [NEXUS-12469](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12469) asks the same question, and references [NEXUS-14407](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-14407): REST Search & Download by 'Latest', released in 3.16, Q4 2019.

> **Extend the search & download service so that users can sort the search results by 'latest version'**.

[Examples](http://community.sonatype.com/t/nxrm-3-16-rest-search-and-filtering-enhancements/1586):

```
http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?repository=maven-central&group=junit&name=junit&sort=version&prerelease=false

curl -L -o myartifact.tar.gz -u xxx:xxx "http://localhost:8080/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&direction=desc&repository=maven-snapshots&maven.groupId=bla.bla.bla&maven.artifactId=bla-bla&maven.extension=tar.gz
```

So a combination of:

- API endpoint `assets/download`
- `sort=version` modifier

Comment: @John Seen Please note that you not only need to use the redirect URL but also the version needs to be specified as LATEST in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Using the REST API in v3 (3.17.0 to be exact) the following should work to get the latest version of any lib:

```
/service/rest/v1/search/assets/download?sort=version&maven.artifactId=artifactId&maven.groupId=groupId&maven.extension=jar
```